# iOS SDK 3.2 Cancel Request or Timeout

Tags: facebook, ios6, sdk, timeout

I'm using the latest FB 3.2 SDK on iOS 6 and testing in the simulator right now.
I have found that I can post a photo to a user's wall fine first time app is run.  I can repeat the post again, ONCE. After the second post, any subsequent posts hang and I get the dreaded com.facebook.sdk error 5 message.

So to handle this, I'm looking for a cancel request in the latest SDK as I'm not using the older FBConnect code... on the basis that when the first hang happens, I cancel the request and try again.

So I need a way to cancel, but also a way to detect a timeout.  Can anybody tell me how to set the timeout using 3.2 ?

[Edit...] I use the Class level methods to use an FBRequestConnection / startWithGraphPath rather than creating the connection with an alloc/initWithTimeout. So I'm looking for something that allows the timeout whilst working with the Class level code, if possible

Thanks

Paul